# Validating configuration files through Unit Tests?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing

I'm building an application where users can choose one of the defined timezones in `config/timezones.php`:

```
return [
    'malta'   => 'Europe/Malta',
    'manila'  => 'Asia/Manila',
    'newyork' => 'America/New_York',
];
```

This file has an array with an identifier and a valid time zone string (as found [on PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php))

I'm trying to build this application based on test driven development, so naturally I wrote a unit test to check if the time changed correctly when a user changed its timezone:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class TimeZoneTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function the_date_and_time_will_be_displayed_based_on_the_timezone_of_the_user() {

        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->create([
            'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila' // +8 hours
        ]);

        $date = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); // 2018-01-01 00:00:00

        $adjustedDate = $date->timezone($user->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // +8 hours = 2018-01-01 08:00:00

        $this->assertEquals('2018-01-01 08:00:00', $adjustedDate);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but here's the problem: if I were to make a typo in the configuration file, the unit test will still pass but the application will break.

I could simply create another unit test where I loop and validate the items of my configuration file using `in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list())`, but I am not sure if that belongs in a unit test. It feels to me that this only needs to be validated once upon committing your code or something.

My questions: **how/where/when do I check if my configuration file is valid before it's deployed to production?**

Comment: try looping through it in a test and creating a date time zone object based on the values. If it works the $x will be an instanceof the class

Comment: Configuration should not be testable through unit tests. So the unit test still working is a good thing. You don't want changes to your configuration to break a test run. A broken / false configuration will lead to false output and while test-driven development is good, do not aim for 100% coverage. If you really want to be sure that your application works, you'll need to add functional tests.

Comment: Sidenote: The `$adjustedDate` should be part of either the User class or a service. You are writing the logic you want to test for, namely: `$date->timezone($user->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` inside the test case. You'll have to repeat that line in every piece of code where you want to use that. Make `timezone` a prive instead of public property and introduce a `getFormattedDate()` method on the user that then uses the timezone to generate that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code collaborates with application configuration, just as it collaborates with services, databases, system calls, etc. In a unit test, you're *supposed* to test code in isolation from collaborators, which implies changing configuration should not affect any unit test.

Thus, to assert failure when configuration is incorrect, you'd turn to an integration test - since integration tests deal with collaborators. The integration test you'd use depends upon where you've implemented the check for configuration sanity.

For example, some projects put configuration checking at the very front of the front controller, so that if any configuration is bogus, there's an immediate exception. If that's where your configuration verification lives, then you'd have something like:

```
/**
 * @expectedException ApplicationException
 * @expectedExceptionCode 500
 */
function test_front_controller_explodes_with_500_error_when_booted_with_bad_configuration() {
    $this->fail('unimplemented');
}
```

Comment: That makes total sense, thanks you for your clear answer!